# Using a <string,string> or <string, char> map instead of <char, char> in C++

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, compiler-errors, char

I am new to STL and want to get used to string datatype instead of the char datatype. I am trying to map a string to a char in this code but it gives 2 compilation errors at lines 13 and 14 - "error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' and error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'". How can I fix these errors?

I have written the correct code in commented lines (using a map of char,char) to show what I want to implement with strings. I think the problem is probably that a string is not taken as an array of characters in C++.

What is the best way to implement the same without using char datatype?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //map<char,char> M;
    map<string, char> M;
    string S,R;
    cin>>S>>R;
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        //M[S[i]]=(char)(i+'a');
        //M[(char)toupper(S[i])]=(char)(i+'A');
        M[S[i]]=(char)(i+'a');
        M[toupper(S[i])]=(char)(i+'A');
    }
    for(int i=0;i<R.size();i++)
        cout<<M[R[i]];
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `string` is not a replacement for a `char`. If you need a `char`, use a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`S[i]` returns a single `char`, while  `toupper()` returns an `int`.  `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts a single `char` by itself (but it does have an `=` operator that does) or an `int` at all.  You need to use something more like this instead:

```
// using string(const char* s, size_type count)
char c = S[i];
M[string(&c, 1)] = (char)(i+'a');
c = (char) toupper(c);
M[string(&c, 1)] = (char)(i+'A');
```

Or:

```
// using string(size_type count, char ch)
char c = S[i];
M[string(1, c)] = (char)(i+'a');
c = (char) toupper(c);
M[string(1, c)] = (char)(i+'A');
```

Or:

```
// using operator=(char ch)
string tmp;
tmp = S[i];
M[tmp] = (char)(i+'a');
tmp = (char) toupper(c);
M[tmp] = (char)(i+'A');
```